# Send collection to procedure as parameter

Tags: vba, excel, object, arguments

I try to commit a collection as a function output to another procedure. This is my code:

```
Function colGen() As Collection
Dim col As Collection
Dim bo As Boolean
Dim str As String
Set col = New Collection
bo = True
str = "Test"
col.Add bo
col.Add str
End Function

Sub test()
Dim col As Collection
Set col = New Collection
Dim str As String
col = colGen
MsgBox (str)
End Sub
```

But in the line `col = colGen` I get the error that "Argument is not optional" but just do not understand why this is. Could anyone help me here?

Comment: Try `Set col = colGen`

Comment: As a collection is an Object, to affect it a new value, you MUST use `Set` keyword, so your line should be `Set col = colGen`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a couple of problems. First, your function doesn't actually return anything. Second you need to use `Set` when assigning objects to variables:

```
Function colGen() As Collection
    Dim col                   As Collection
    Dim bo                    As Boolean
    Dim str                   As String
    Set col = New Collection
    bo = True
    str = "Test"
    col.Add bo
    col.Add str
    Set colGen = col
End Function

Sub test()
    Dim col                   As Collection
    Dim str                   As String
    Set col = colGen
    ' str has no value
    ' so check the collection
    MsgBox col(2)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

As **a Collection is an Object**, to **affect it a new value, you MUST use `Set` keyword**, so your line should be

`Set col = colGen`

instead of

`col = colGen`

Just like you did `Set col = New Collection`

---

You also forget to define the output of your function, so here is your amended code :

```
Function colGen() As Collection
    Dim col As Collection, _
        bo As Boolean, _
        str As String

    Set col = New Collection

    bo = True
    str = "Test"

    col.Add bo
    col.Add str

    'You must assign your output value
    'As it is an object, you MUST use "Set"
    Set colGen = col
End Function

Sub test()
    Dim col As Collection, _
        str As String

    Set col = New Collection

    col = colGen
    str = col(col.Count)
    MsgBox (str)
End Sub
```